# How can I tell which wire to connect to a bayonett lamp connector?

Tags: lamp

I have a white bayonet lamp connector that has no markings to show where to connect the brown and blue wires. [image: connector]
Any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't  matter. Either wire to either side will complete the circuit once the bulb is in place.

Comment: Agreed, If it mattered, the bayonet would also need to be polarised rather than symmetric - but as it is you can insert the bulb in either of two orientations rotated 180 degrees apart. Both connections are equally insulated.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick what is that hole with metal showing inside in the front edge of the socket--a ground? Is there an identical hole on the other side? What is the method of connection in these fixtures? Are there screw clamps of different color and material (indicating hot to one and neural to the other?

Comment: @Jim: See [my answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/132190/2815)

Comment: @Jim - the holes are the screws for tightening the wires in place. There is nothing on the connector to indicate where either of the wires go.

Answer (score 0):

If it's bayonet in my understanding of the word, and it certainly looks like it is, since the picture plainly shows the J-hook.

The blue goes to the terminal that connects to the shell of the socket, i.e. The part with the little slots in it.   The brown goes to the nub in the middle.   This choice makes you less likely to be shocked while changing a bulb.

Blue is **neutral** and is designed to have a voltage near earth.

Cheapie LEDs often do a shoddy job of insulating the exposed parts. But just the same, the engineers try to make it so if it fails, it fails with exposed parts faulting to the shell.  If you wire the socket correctly, this improves safety.

Answer (score 0):

In UK wiring, it doesn't matter which wire goes where in that particular [B22 bayonet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonet_mount#Light_bulbs) fitting. I'm guessing the same is most likely true in Australia too.

Here's an equivalent fitting for a typical pendant lampholder - you can see it is completely symmetrical.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Even with the type of lampholder with metal conductive bodies, there is no connection between either of the pins and the shell. The shell has a separate ground connection.

Again the notional live and neutral elements are completetly symmetric - it doesn't matter which one is connected to live and which to neutral

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In fittings where it does matter, Live and Neutral will be clearly marked. For example with "L", "N" and "⏚" or "E".

[image]

Comment: your photos are very similar - only two wires to connect. I guess it would be marked if there needed to be a particular way to wire it. Thanks for your response,